# Defining a function returning another function based on a reference

Tags: ocaml

The following piece of code does not work as I thought it would :

```ml
let debug_flag = ref false

let dprintf = let open Printf in
  match !debug_flag with
  | true -> printf
  | false -> ifprintf stdout

let test_dprintf () =
  begin
    debug_flag := true;
    Printf.printf "print1\n";
    dprintf "print2\n";
    Printf.printf "print3\n";
    debug_flag := false
  end
```

I would expect it to output

```
print1
print2
print3
```

However it only prints

```
print1
print3
```

Assigning `true` to `debug_flag` in `test_dprintf` does not seem to have any impact at all.

Does anyone know why? And if so, do you know of a possible way to workaround?

I am using OCaml 4.09.0

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of `dprintf` is not a function expression. It is an expression that will return a function, but the expression itself will be evaluated only when evaluating the definition of `dprintf`, not when the function it returns is called.

To solve this, you could just make the argument explicit:

```
let dprintf fmt = let open Printf in
  match !debug_flag with
  | true -> printf fmt
  | false -> ifprintf stdout fmt
```

Now the body of `dprintf` will be evaluated when it's called.